# How to strengthen my forearms?

Tags: strength, workout, definition, forearm

17 year old athlete, 190lb 5'11"
I want to really gain some definition and strength for my forearms but don't really know how to go about it. Any recommendations on good exercises to do or other methods?

Comment: Finger tip curls, and pretty much any exercise that bends your hands/wrist towards your forearm.

Answer (score 4):

Behind the back wrist curls have always been a favorite of mine. Just hold a straight bar behind you with both hands, wrists faces away from you, and curls your wrists up towards your forearms, hold for a sec and release.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to hammer curls with a dumbbell. If you've never done them, they're called hammer curls because they mimic the feel of grabbing a hammer. They're great for working the top of the forearm.